# WPF - How to explicitely set the index of an item inside a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

Let's say I want to display information on a specific row of a ListView (displayed horizontally here, so it's technically columns) to simulate calendar-like visual information.

[Result structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfgls.png)

First row is a list of day numbers (1st-31st of July).

The two other rows are numbers coming from two different CSV exports where I compare two numbers for that same day.

I'm using a first ListView for dates which remains static, and displays a List of integers.
I'm using another ListView which contains a "DayData" model.

```
public class DayData
{
    // Top number displayed
    public float topNumber { get; set; }

    // Bottom number displayed
    public float bottomNumber { get; set; }

    // Matching day for this entry
    public int matchingDay { get; set; }

    // Color used to alert user in case of bad ratio
    public string color { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Object"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DayData()
    {
        this.topNumber = -1;
        this.bottomNumber = -1;
    }
}
```

Now my issue is, when the compared numbers are empty for that day, I want the list to display an "empty" entry, or at least display some kind of margin to align the numbers correctly, so that the DayData fits their matching day number, like so :

[Result wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05D17.png)

You'd probably suggest to add a "null" entry into the list, however this causes performance issues, as another ListView hosts the whole thing, which itself displays several entries of ListViews + other stuff at once. 
However, there aren't any issues when I display only the DayData entries, as the ListView will never contain more than 20 at once over a month.

Is there any workaround, like a Grid control with data templating where I could set the rows and columns myself and bind them to the DayData model to align them correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you are not using columns?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I can't use columns inside of a ListView. There isn't any notion of columns, and neither of rows. Only of "Items" which are automatically stacked.

Comment: On its own a `ListView` behaves a lot like a `Listbox`. However, you can change the representation of items at will by changing the `View` property. The out-the-box implementaton is `GridView`, which will let you use columns http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

Comment: I'm not sure how I could implement this, since I have to add the columns manually in xaml instead of just letting the binding do the work of populating the list...

Comment: Try creating a class that inherits from `GridView` and allows you to populate columns through a binding.

Comment: I can't bind the "Columns" property of a GridView, which contains all of the column definitions, since it's apparently not a Dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd use columns for every item which will make your problem disappear as you can resize columns. List view:

```
    <ListView x:Name="testCaseView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="737" Margin="0,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1914" FontFamily="Eras ITC" Foreground="Black">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding testCase}" Header="Test Case" Width="auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding condition}" Header="Condition" Width="auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding description}" Header="Description" Width="auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding expectedResults}" Header="Expected Results" Width="auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

C# create an item to hold all fields of a row:

```
public class TestCaseItem
{
    public String testCase { get; set; }
    public String condition { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public String expectedResults { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate listview:

```
testCaseView.Items.Add(new TestCaseItem { testCase = "", condition = "", description = "", expectedResults = "" });
```

Comment: The thing is I can't just define them manually in xaml. I should be able to add them programatically depending on the size of the list of Days (the amount of days in a month can vary).

Comment: You want a separate column for every day for every item?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the screenshots in the original post.